# O que são os comandos Python com underscore no inicio e no fim?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Percebo que alguns scripts em Python possuem expressões com comandos assim:

```
__name__ == “__main__”'
__str__,__repr__ 
self.__class__ self.__dict__
```

O que são esses comandos que começam e terminam com underscore?

Comment: Leia isto: [Um ou dois sublinhados?](http://aprenda-python.blogspot.com/2013/05/um-ou-dois-sublinhados.html)

Comment: Fiz uma piadinha com isso: `__cats__, __cats__, Hoooo!`